# Flutter textfield design like image

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to know, how do I make a textfield or textformfield like the image. [image: Image one]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have put together a simple code just to give you an idea.

```
  Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.purple),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
    ),
    child: IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(color: Colors.purple, borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(radius), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(radius))),
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text("BROWSE"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none, hintText: "Choose your pic", hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple.shade400)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

---

which looks like

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

I will give you tips how to make it , You can use card widget and List tile , the rest of it is easy .

for example :

```
Card(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        const ListTile(
          leading: here to put image,
          title: Here to put textfild,
          subtitle: extra text,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```